# How to iterate over a row in a SciPy sparse matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a sparse matrix random matrix created as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import rand
foo = rand(100, 100, density=0.1, format='csr')
```

I want to iterate over the cells in a particular row and perform two calculations:

```
row1 = foo.getrow(bar1)
row2 = foo.getrow(bar2)

"""
Like the following:
sum1 = 0
sum2 = 0
for each cell x in row1:
    sum1 += x
    if the corresponding cell (in the same column) in row2 y is non-zero:
        sum2 += x*y
"""
```

Comment: Are you just looking for a solution or the an efficient one?

Comment: An efficient one, I'd rather not use "todense" for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach -

```
# Get first row summation by simply using sum method of sparse matrix
sum1 = row1.sum()

# Get the non-zero indices of first row
idx1 = row1.indices
data1 = row1.data  # Or get sum1 here with : `data1.sum()`.

# Get the non-zero indices of second row and corresponding data
idx2 = row2.indices
data2 = row2.data

# Get mask of overlap from row1 nonzeros on row2 nonzeros. 
# Select those from data2 and sum those up for the second summation o/p.
sum2 = data1[np.in1d(idx1,idx2)].dot(data2[np.in1d(idx2,idx1)])
```

Alternatively, as suggested in [`comments by @user2357112`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41749347/how-to-iterate-over-a-row-in-a-scipy-sparse-matrix/41749675?noredirect=1#comment70693443_41749675), we can simply use `matrix-multiplication` to get the second summation -

```
sum2 = sum((row1*row2.T).data)
```

Comment: It looks to me like you could use `row1 * row2.T` to simplify most of the `sum2` calculation.

Comment: @user2357112 Good idea! Added into post. Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting an intermittent error with (row1*row2.T).data[0].  Does this work if there are no collisions e.g. when the product is 0?

Comment: @tyebillion Yeah that was a bug indeed. Should be fixed now. Check it out!